# How to find records in one table which aren't in another

Tags: oracle

I'm very new to oracle sql and programming and I need some help with one of my first projects. I'm working with this table schema:

```
Column  Data Type   Length  Precision   Scale   Nullable
EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER    22      6           0        No
START_DATE  DATE      7        -          -        No
END_DATE    DATE      7        -          -        No
JOB_ID     VARCHAR2   10       -          -        No
DEPARTMENT_ID   NUMBER  22     4          0        Yes
```

I want to display all employees who have never changed their jobs, not even once(employees not listed in the above table) This table is labeled job_history. How would I go about doing this? I'm not sure on how to get this started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from employees
where employee_id not in ( select employee_id from job_history)
/
```

Comment: awesome thank you very much, I will mark as answer in 7 minutes when it lets me, lol.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a left join and check for a null employee_id on the job_history table.

```
select * from employees 
left join job_history 
on job_history.employee_id = employees.employee_id 
where job_history.employee_id is NULL
```

Answer (score -1):

Fairly often an execution plan is better for

```
select * from employees e where not exists 
  (select 1 from job_history jh.employee_id = e.employee_id)
```

than "not in ()".
And if the tables have the same structure the best result will with

```
select * from employees 
minus
select * from job_history
```

Comment: Execution plans are tricky things.  The merits of `NOT IN` versus `NOT EXISTS` are subject to various considerations, but especially the number of rows in each table.  But definitely the `MINUS` operation is *not* "the best result": it forces the database to read the whole `job_history` table.  Whereas we only need to read the `jh.employee_id` column, which is probably indexed.  If the tables have many columns that is a lot of unnecessary IO.

Comment: Also of course the `MINUS` will return the *wrong* results.  As `job_history` is a journalling table it won't match any rows in `employees`, which just has the current state.

Comment: My bad - I mean select employee_id from employees minus select employee_id from job_history. And I wrote 'fairly often'. For NOT EXISTS it's enough to find one correspond record and not necessarily to make join in its entirety.